# PrimeNg p-calendar translate

Tags: angular, calendar, translation, primeng

what is the better way of translating p-calendar of primeNG in Angular?

It says Locale is no longer in use and to use i18n API.
How to implement that, and how to call it in the p-calendar?
Is there a better way of doing it?